# OAuth2 with Firebase Admin Node.js SDK and Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: node.js, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-api-js-client

I’m building an app that will use Firebase Admin Node.js SDK (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node and https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup ) to send push notifications to mobile devices. At the moment for development purposes I’m using the service account from my own Firebase project but intend to allow users to use their own Firebase projects.

To do this, I could get the user’s project id, client email and private key, store them and use them to initialize the Admin object whenever a user wants to send an email:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey:"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

But I’d prefer not to keep this data in my db as well as make it easier for the user to authenticate my app, so I’m exploring the possibility of initializing the admin object using a Google OAuth2 refresh token:

```
var refreshToken; // Get refresh token from OAuth2 flow

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.refreshToken(refreshToken),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

My question is, using this way how would I configure the credential to use a specific Firebase project (like with the projectId: "PROJECT_ID" in the admin.credential.cert method above)?

I see in the reference docs for admin.credential (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential) it says that “The refresh token credential does not grant access to every admin API.” 
Is it possible to use this flow for Firebase Cloud Messaging and if not, what would be the recommended way forward?

Comment: Is this service or app your building intended for multiple people to use? Meaning multiple people would potentially call `initializeApp`?

Comment: Yes, the app is intended as a service for users to send notifications. So on my server the initializeApp method would used with the user's Firebase project (not mine).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to authenticate Firebase Admin using a refresh token but after the `admin.initializeApp` call, attempting to access the database errors with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of null`

Comment: No, not solved yet